# Upgrading "initialization from incompatible pointer type" warning to an error

Tags: gcc, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am working on a code base that's compiled with gcc, which is doing a lot of initialisation of structures containing function pointers.

Whenever anyone makes a mistake with the function types I get the warning "initialization from incompatible pointer type". I would like to upgrade this to an error, because it's obviously wrong.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find what the compiler option name of this warning is to use with `-Werror='. And turning all warnings into errors isn't an options here (for reasons which are not relevant right now).

Apparently adding `-fdiagnostics-show-option` is supposed to annotate each compiler warning with the compiler option name, and indeed, it does so... for all warnings except this one. So now I'm confused. Any suggestions?

This is gcc 4.4.5 for ARM, running on Linux.